# Keras CNN predict error

Tags: keras

I have a simple Convolution1D model, that I have trained successfully

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocabsize, output_dim=32, 
input_length=STR_MAX_LEN, dropout=0.2))    
model.add(Dropout(0.2))    
model.add(Convolution1D(64, 5, activation='relu', border_mode='same'))    
model.add(Dropout(0.2))    
model.add(MaxPooling1D())    
model.add(Flatten())    
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))    
model.add(Dropout(0.7))    
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))    
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(),  metrics=['accuracy'])    
model.summary()
```

Model Summary as below

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)          (None, 500, 32)       160000      embedding_input_1[0][0]          
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)              (None, 500, 32)       0           embedding_1[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution1d_1 (Convolution1D)  (None, 500, 64)       10304       dropout_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)              (None, 500, 64)       0           convolution1d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1D)    (None, 250, 64)       0           dropout_2[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)              (None, 16000)         0           maxpooling1d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 100)           1600100     flatten_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)              (None, 100)           0           dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 1)             101         dropout_3[0][0]                  
====================================================================================================
Total params: 1770505
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

And I have a text that I need to run prediction on.

```
text = "dont know what could have saved limp dispiriting yam but it definitely wasnt a lukewarm mushroom as murky and appealing as bong water"
textWordsArray = np.array(text.split())
textIdxArrayPadded = 
sequence.pad_sequences(textWordsIdxArray,maxlen=STR_MAX_LEN, value=0)
textIdxArrayPadded
```

structure of the text input

```
array([[    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,  5363,   121,    48,    97,
           25,  1891,  8849, 51645, 19831,    18,     9,   404, 15422,     3, 15610, 27479,    14,
         7217,     2,  2273,    14, 36597,  1090]], dtype=int32)
```

However, I am getting the below error when i run the prediction.

prediction = model.predict(textIdxArrayPadded, batch_size=1,verbose=1)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-818365da75ca> in <module>()
----> 1 prediction = model.predict(textIdxArrayPadded, batch_size=1,verbose=1)

/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.pyc in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose)
    669         if self.model is None:
    670             self.build()
--> 671         return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    672 
    673     def predict_on_batch(self, x):

/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose)
   1177         f = self.predict_function
   1178         return self._predict_loop(f, ins,
-> 1179                                   batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
   1180 
   1181     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in _predict_loop(self, f, ins, batch_size, verbose)
    876                 ins_batch = slice_X(ins, batch_ids)
    877 
--> 878             batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    879             if type(batch_outs) != list:
    880                 batch_outs = [batch_outs]

/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.pyc in __call__(self, inputs)
    715     def __call__(self, inputs):
    716         assert type(inputs) in {list, tuple}
--> 717         return self.function(*inputs)
    718 
    719 

/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    869                     node=self.fn.nodes[self.fn.position_of_error],
    870                     thunk=thunk,
--> 871                     storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
    872             else:
    873                 # old-style linkers raise their own exceptions

/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/link.pyc in raise_with_op(node, thunk, exc_info, storage_map)
    312         # extra long error message in that case.
    313         pass
--> 314     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
    315 
    316 

/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    857         t0_fn = time.time()
    858         try:
--> 859             outputs = self.fn()
    860         except Exception:
    861             if hasattr(self.fn, 'position_of_error'):

IndexError: One of the index value is out of bound. Error code: 65535.\n
Apply node that caused the error: GpuAdvancedSubtensor1(GpuElemwise{Composite{Switch(i0, (i1 * i2 * i3), i2)},no_inplace}.0, Elemwise{Cast{int64}}.0)
Toposort index: 38
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix), TensorType(int64, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(5000, 32), (500,)]
Inputs strides: [(32, 1), (8,)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[GpuReshape{3}(GpuAdvancedSubtensor1.0, MakeVector{dtype='int64'}.0)]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

Comment: do you have any logs of the training?

Something seem to be off with the network.. your output class dimension is binary, but the sequence you predicting on has values 0 -  51649 of what I can see. The error message occurs as something make is it go out of bound <65535.

Comment: Meaning you have to many classes given `sigmoid` as output layer

Comment: This was solved for me in one of the other forums, I will post the solution here

Answer (score 0):

I had the embeddings limited to the vocabsize, however I forgot to limit the word id to vocabsize

This was answered for me in a different forum , posting the solution here from the author.

> @niazangels Niyas Mohammed Looks like you forgot to limit the
>   vocabulary to 5000 when encoding your test input!

Limit the vocabulary size to 5000

```
textWordsIdxArray = [np.array([i if i < vocabsize -1 else vocabsize -1 for i in s]) for s in textWordsIdxArray]
```